# ¿Por qué el .prop("checked", false) no funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Necesito ayuda con un `checkbox`, que tengo en un modal. cuando el modal se cierre quiero que el `checkbox` se desmarque ya probé muchas opciones y nada funciona.

```
$('#Matutino').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
$('input[name="Matutino"]').removeAttr('checked');
$('input[name="Matutino"][value="1"]').removeAttr("checked").trigger("change");
$('#Matutino').prop('checked', false).
```

y de paso como puedo hacer que un `div` aparezca como desestabilizado. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: En el que dice `.prop('checked',false).checkboxradio...` para qué usas la función de `checkboxradio`?

Comment: Otra manera que encontre por ahi para desmarcar el checkbox

Comment: No uses `.checkboxradio` esa función es para transformar un checkbox html a uno de jQuery, y al hacer eso se resetea el `.prop('checked',false')`. Con que hagas `$('#Matutino').prop('checked', false)` es más que suficiente. Siempre y cuando el id de tu input sea el correcto y tengas jQuery con su versión más actual, o la que cubre la función de `prop()`

Comment: Y he intentando solo con esa opcion $('#Matutino').prop('checked', false). Pero aun asi no funciona el jquery esta actualizado

Comment: Fatlará más código y html para poder entonces verificar cual podría ser el problema

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#modal-responsive").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
  

  if($("#Matutino").is(":checked"))
  {
   alert("hola");
   //$('#Matutino').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
   // $('input[name="Matutino"]').removeAttr('checked');
   $('input[name="Matutino"][value="1"]').removeAttr("checked").trigger("change");
   
  }

 });

 
}); </script>

Comment: Es todo el codigo, lo que requiero que haga es que al ocultar el modal se desmarque mi checkbox

Answer (score 1):

depende de la version de JQuery que uses, funciona o no. Esto se soluciona usando `attr` en vez de `prop`.

Ya me dices ;)

Answer (score 0):

Porque no ocupas solo una función anónima es decir algo similar a esto yo lo utilizo para validar mi login pero en vez del control de botón ocupa solo la instrucción  $('#Matutino').prop('checked', false);

**NOTA** TU ETIQUETA DE ESCRIPT PONLA AL ULTIMO

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtusername").on("change", function () {
            $eval = $("#txtusername").val();
            $eval2 = $("#txtPass").val();
            $btnval = $('#btnStartLogin');
            if ($eval != "" && $eval2 != "") {
                $("#btnStartLogin").show();
                $("#btnStartLogin").prop("disabled", false);
            }
            else if ($eval == "" && $eval2 != "") {
                $("#btnStartLogin").prop("visible", false);
                $("#btnStartLogin").prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else if ($eval != "" && $eval2 == "") {
                $("#btnStartLogin").prop("visible", false);
                $("#btnStartLogin").prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else if ($eval2 == "" && $eval == "") {
                $("#btnStartLogin").hide();
                $("#btnStartLogin").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
```